# troubleshooting a website that doesn't give errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net web forms, web application that I am working on where the user fills out a form that is currently a paper form and we are trying to get it on an ipad. The form is filled out and then using a .net windows form webbrowser control and bitmap library, I take a screen shot of the form and save it to a server on the local network. The applications works 100% of the time when I run it in debug mode out of visual studio 2013, regardless of web browser. As soon as I publish to IIS 7.5 running on the same machine I am developing on to test it out, it stops working. Everything returns 200 codes like it should but the image of the form does not get saved and I get no errors. I added a console property to the class I'm using to create the image of the form that adds statements after each line of code that I then write to the web browser console and all lines of code are being executed. I don't know what to do next to try and figure out why this isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: "What's wrong with my code," questions are bad enough by themselves, but at least they normally *come with* code...

Comment: I wasn't asking "What's wrong with my code" I would like to try and figure that out on my own. I was more asking what suggestions people have for troubleshooting their code when they have no error messages to go on.

Comment: Take a screen shot of the form? Don't you have a database you can save the fields into? Or if not, write it into json files or something.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the form has to be saved into a jpg image so it can then be uploaded and used by another app we currently use. Also why am I getting downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

My gut tells me this may be a permissions problem. Have you ensured the security context under which your IIS app domain is running as write permissions to the folder in which you are storing the files?  In 'debug' mode, your user account may already have permissions, but not so with the IIS security context.  You may be getting access denied errors that you are somehow swallowing in your code.  Just a hunch.  Post more details for better diagnosis.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but I changed the permissions on the folder and that had no effect. I'm going to run Procmon on the file server later today to see if that can give me some insight.

Comment: Can you post the server-side code that is supposed to save the jpg to the file server. I'm confused as to how you have added a console property on the server side that is outputting log messages on the browser/client side.